# How to connect to Database app path - vb6

Tags: vb6

Im trying to connect my databases(not binded/flexible) and it will run when the form activated. But in my code it kept error and didn't connected to the database. This is my last code:

```
Private Sub LoginForm_Activate()
    Aadodc1.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & App.Path & "\Database\Login.mdb;Persist Security Info=False"
    Aadodc2.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & App.Path & "\Database\login.mdb;Persist Security Info=False"
End Sub
```

I have ever connected it through the adodc property. But after i run it it broke if i move the folder to another folder so i tried to connect it using a flexible connectionstring.

Comment: What error are you getting? Do you actually `Open` that connection anywhere? What is the value of `App.Path`, and why do you need two connections?

Comment: Error: Cannot find the valid path. I don't know how to open the connection and the value off app.path. Just now I'm trying to make the app.path code. In the past I connect my database through the property and not through the code. About the connections, I made 11 adodcs and 5 databases. I do this to seperate the database function.  So 1 of my database only for settings, 1 for login and others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found it out, the adodc should be refreshed `Aadodc1.Refresh` and the record source `Aadodc1.RecordSource = "Select * from [table name]"` must be defined. That's all :)